# Show woocommerce stock quantity as individual numbers

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to load stock quantity of products on a custom page of my website. I use this to get the stock quantity

```
        <p class="stock-m13"><?php echo $product->get_stock_quantity(); ?></p>
```

This will return the exact number of stock quantity of a product, lets say 3. What I want to do is show the stock quantity as 1 1 1 instead of 3. I am thinking of a counter but I cannot really know the way to do it.

Thank you

Comment: You can use a for loop: for($i=1; $i<=$product->get_stock_quantity(); $i++) { echo $i; } to do that.

Comment: Do you mean something like `for ($i=0; $i<$product->get_stock_quantity(); $i++) { echo ("1 "); }`?

Comment: @talkdirty Thanks a lot. That did the job

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
for ($s = 0; $s < $product->get_stock_quantity(); $s++) {
   echo "<p class='stock-m13'>".$product->get_stock_quantity()."</p>";
}
?>
```

or if you want display just 1 in quantity

```
<?php
for ($s = 0; $s < $product->get_stock_quantity(); $s++) {
   echo "<p class='stock-m13'>1</p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Hello, the 1st code you sent me showed the quantity as many times as the quantity is. For example if a product's quantity is 3, it showed me 3 3 3 and not 1 1 1. Thank you for your time though to answer me

Comment: Yes because you need create a function and this function return the quantity for one line, is the best practice ;) no problème for help we are here for that :)